# Deleting objects in Django

Tags: django, forms, object, django-views

In a mini blog app, I want to create a delete function, so that the owner of the blog can delete his entries (and only his entries).
I guess that the only methods for doing do, is using a form.
Though my the deletion code seems clear and correct, it doesn't work.
My code:

```
def delete_new(request,id):
   u = New.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = DeleteNewForm(request.POST)    
       form.u.delete()             
       form.save()   
   return render_to_response('news/deleteNew.html', {
           'form': form,
           }, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in the template:

```
<a href='/news/delete_new/{{object.id}}/'> Delete</a> <br />
```

Is this a correct approach? I mean, creating a form for this?
also, the only way to take the blog post associated with the deletion link is having an id as a parameter. Is it right? I mean, maybe any user can type another id, in the url, and delete another entry (eventually not one of his)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, for deleting objects you should rather use POST (or DELETE) [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

If you really want to use HTTP GET for your example, here is what you need to fix:

If you have url pointing to some url like yours: `<a href='/news/delete_new/{{object.id}}/'> Delete</a>` then you can simply write view that will check if object belongs to logged in user and delete this entry if yes, like in code you have already written:

```
def delete_new(request,id):
   #+some code to check if New belongs to logged in user
   u = New.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
```

To check if New objects belogs to some user you need to create realation between `User` and `New` (like `created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)` in `New` model).

You can get logged in user this way: `request.user`

I hope I got your point correctly and my answer helps you somehow.

PS: You can also consider using `{% url %}` tag instead of writing urls directly in your templates.

Comment: it rolls smoothly, and in just one line:
   u = New.objects.filter(created_by = request.user).get(pk=id).delete()
thank you! :)

Comment: Exactly, you can add some error handling if there is no such New object for a given user and display nice error message (with your one liner it will fails loudly with 500 error). But basically that is all what you need to do here:) I'm glad that my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a form and checking POST, because GETs to pages are not supposed to change the state on the server. (Although, in practice what's happening here is relatively 'safe')

Comment: Doing this would open your website up to CSRF, as no token is transmitted/required.

Comment: This is *not* safe and enables CSRF attacks in which a user deletes content belonging to other users.

Answer (score 35):

You need to use a form, or you're vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). You're also deleting the model before you've checked whether the request was a GET or a POST.

Create a simple `ModelForm`:

```
from django import forms

from .models import New

class DeleteNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = New
        fields = []
```

In your views.py in the same Django app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .forms import DeleteNewForm
from .models import New

def delete_new(request, new_id):
    new_to_delete = get_object_or_404(New, id=new_id)
    #+some code to check if this object belongs to the logged in user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteNewForm(request.POST, instance=new_to_delete)

        if form.is_valid(): # checks CSRF
            new_to_delete.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/") # wherever to go after deleting

    else:
        form = DeleteNewForm(instance=new_to_delete)

    template_vars = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'news/deleteNew.html', template_vars)
```

Comment: To explain why this is best: in ANY case, submits, updates and deletes MUST use POST (or PUT) requests. GET requests can be masked in otherwise inoffensive-looking links. Say, if a major site had a simple "Delete all my stuff" at example.com/account/delete/, I could hide such a link in a blog post, or in TinyURL-like services. Upon visit, you'd see a nice "Your profile was deleted." page.


Hybrid methods such as Wilfred Hughes', display a confirmation page on GET, that contains a form with a CSRF token. POST requests validate for CSRF and then ultimately delete the requested resource.