# Django .delete() does not work

Tags: python, django

I am making a simple bbs in Django.

At the moment, I am trying to make it possible to delete a post in front-end.

This is my code in views.py

```
@login_required
def delete_post(request, id):
    post_to_delete = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)

    if post_to_delete.owner_user != request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeletePostForm(request.POST, instance=post_to_delete)
        if form.is_valid():
            post_to_delete.delete()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 
    else:
        form = DeletePostForm(instance=post_to_delete)

    return render(request,'delete_post.html', {'form':form})
```

I believe I am using the .delete() function correctly and when I click my delete button, I am taken to the delete_post.html but when i go back to check the list of posts in admin, the post is still there..

Comment: you need to check that you call to form.is_valid() is returning True. If you dont know, you can see the errors using form.errors

And also, I dont know why are you using a Form to perfom a Delete, just passing the post id to the view and getting it, you can delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13644671  I saw it here.. it tells me to use form to avoid csrf attack.

Comment: You dont need use forms to avoid csrf attacks, because Django handle it for you, you can check how it works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#unprotected-view-needs-the-csrf-token

Comment: Just to make sure, if I add @csrf_protect on top of my def delete_post, I will get automatic csrf protection?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: @Dan you dont need to add it, Django do it for you.

Comment: When you click delete, you be taken to your homepage `'/'` not `delete_post.html`. as @levi said, check that `form.is_valid()` is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after explain to you that you dont need a form to delete a instance. Let me give to you a versión without use a form.

```
@login_required
def delete_post(request, id):
    post_to_delete = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)

    if post_to_delete.owner_user != request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    if request.method == 'POST':   
        post_to_delete.delete()
        return render(request,'delete_post.html', {'deleted':True})

    return render(request,'delete_post.html', {'deleted':False})
```

You can use `deleted` var as you wish in your template.

Comment: I implemented exactly what you wrote but without checking if request was a POST.. somehow this does not work.. I guess I will figure that out later

Comment: @Dan You should check if is a POST because Delete is a POST action, its a good practice. Remember, GET requests is for retrieving info from your app, POST requests is for modifying it.