# Django object deletion does not work

Tags: python, django, object

I've spend hours today figuring out how to delete objects in Django.
Now I have found and tried 4 different approaches on the Net, that only differ in whether a form/POST/GET approach is used or not. CSRF attacks are irrelevant for me, as the page is supposed to run locally.

What does the app do? So far only uploading files under a certain project name. This name is slugified and used as a key to hash files of a project together.  Now I want to also delete files (later whole projects).

Here one of the approaches:

In the `.html`:

```
<a href="{{file.pk}}/delete" class="btn btn-sm" role="button" title="Delete File">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

This link is diplayed in a detail view, so the url already looks somethin like /files/SLUG/

Then in  `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^upload/$', views.file_upload, name ='upload'),
url(r'^upload/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.file_upload, name ='upload'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.file_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete$', views.file_delete, name="file_delete"),
]
```

And finally the `views.py`:

```
def file_delete(request, slug=None, pk=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(File, slug=slug, pk=pk)
    # instance = File.objects.filter(pk=pk, slug=slug)[0] # the same as above
    instance.delete() #does not work

    return redirect("index") # or anything, this part is no problem
```

Everything runs through without any errors, but when I check the database on /admin, no file is gone. It simply does not get deleted. Sometimes, when logging in on /admin after trying a couple of times, I see multiple "File successfully deleted" messages at the login screen. But then the files are still in the database list.

Django Docs tells me delete() should return some kind of dictionary and how many objects were deleted e.g. like so:

```
>>> e.delete()
(1, {'weblog.Entry': 1})
```

But in may case it just says: None or returns a path starting with a slug.

I'd be very gratefull for any hint. I know there is at least one other post on stackoverflow concerning this, but unfortunately no answers

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124658/django-delete-object) useful?

Comment: Why your a tag doesnt have file-slug.?

Comment: @durdenk: there are multiple files, that share a slug. It is used like a project name, where a project can contain multiple files. Here I only want to delete a certain file, not the whole project. That's why I use .pk and not the slug

Comment: @EbraHim: Thanks. I also tried this approach but don't understand all of it and don't have enough reputation to ask in a comment...
How would the html call look for this approach? I mean the <a href> or whatever that calls the deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [queryset delete method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#delete) (e.g. `File.objects.filter(...).delete()`) returns a tuple.

When you [delete an instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects) (e.g. `instance.delete()`) it returns `None`.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'when I check the file list, no file is gone'. Note that when you delete a model instance, it will remove the row from the database. If the model has a `FileField`, it won't automatically delete the associated file.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem (that's how I found this), and I think if you simply put a '/' in the end of the URL for delete, it should work. At least thats what worked with me.

```
...
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/<<<<$', views.file_delete, name="file_delete"),
    ]
```